# How do you declare a variable so that the value doesn't change on each DOM render?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

How would I declare a variable so that the value doesn't change when the DOM re-renders?

Right now I'm declaring "var slider" in the global scope and changing its value in "function replay" so I can use that value in the "play", "pause", and "resume" functions.

This solution works but when the DOM re-renders "var slider" runs again and the variable "slider" is back to being undefined.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, Fragment } from "react";
import * as slide from "slidetag";

const LessonReplay = props => {
  const [clicked, setClicked] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchEntry = async () => {
      let res = await fetch(`/api/entries/lessonred/${props.match.params.id}`);
      res = await res.json();
      resp = JSON.parse(res[0].recording);
      console.log("1", resp);
      replay(resp);

    };
    fetchEntry();
  }, []);



  var slider;                                                  // Declared here

  function replay(pages) {
    slider = new slide.player(pages);                          // Value set here

  }

  function play() {
    slider.play();                                             // Used here
  }

  function pause() {
    slider.pause();                                            // Used here
    // setClicked(true);
  }

  function resume() {
    slider.resume();                                           // Used here
    // setClicked(false);
  }

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <div className="footer">
        <button onClick={play}>Play</button>

        <button onClick={clicked ? "" : resume} disabled={clicked}>
          Resume
        </button>
        <button onClick={clicked ? "" : pause()} disabled={clicked}>
          Pause
        </button>
      </div>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default LessonReplay;
```

Comment: Have you tried this?
`const [slider, setSlider] = useState(null);

function replay(pages) {
    setSlider(new slide.player(pages));
}`

Comment: Hey Suazithustra. Thanks for the suggestion. I tried that but it didn't work. I'm pretty new to React so maybe it was because I implemented it wrong. useRef worked though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `useRef` for that which maintains a immutable reference which does not change on successive renders unless we set it.

```
const clickedRef = useRef(false);

// Somewhere in a callback or useEffect you can then do 

clickedRef.current = true;
```

For your use case you can do something like this.

```
const sliderRef = useRef(); 

  function replay(pages) {
    sliderRef.current = new slide.player(pages);                          
  }

  function play() {
    if(sliderRef.current) {
       sliderRef.current.play();
    }
  }

  function pause() {
    if(sliderRef.current) {
       sliderRef.current.pause();
    }
  }

  function resume() {
    if(sliderRef.current) {
       sliderRef.current.resume();
    }
  }
```

Comment: Wow! I started reading up on useref after seeing your response. This thing is magic. Thank you sooo much!! Everything works with useRef!